# Why does slider value return null?

Tags: flutter, getter-setter

I'm building a page with multiple styled sliders, so I made a separate SliderWidget class. The slider itself behaves normally, but when I try to print the value of the slider to console, it returns null as `flutter: null`.

I've tried putting specific int values into my currentValue variable (in the SliderWidget class) to test with no luck, so I'm pretty sure that the problem is the getter itself, but I can't figure out what is wrong. I'm pretty new to flutter, so it's very possible I did something stupid.

Here is the slider object:

```
SliderWidget moodSlider = new SliderWidget(
      sliderHeight: 48,
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      color1: 0xFF9BC1BC,
      color2: 0xFF9BC1BC);
```

Here is the SliderWidget class:

```
import 'package:first_tutorial/MoodUpdate/custom_thumb_circle.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double sliderHeight;
  final int min;
  final int max;
  final fullWidth;
  final int color1;
  final int color2;
  final int number;

  SliderWidget(
      {this.sliderHeight,
      this.max,
      this.min,
      this.fullWidth = false,
      this.color1,
      this.color2,
      this.number});

  @override
  _SliderWidgetState createState() => _SliderWidgetState();
}

class _SliderWidgetState extends State<SliderWidget> {
  double currentValue = 0;

  int get number => currentValue.round();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double paddingFactor = .2;

    if (this.widget.fullWidth) paddingFactor = .3;

    return Container(
      width: this.widget.fullWidth
          ? double.infinity
          : (this.widget.sliderHeight) * 5.5,
      height: (this.widget.sliderHeight),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular((this.widget.sliderHeight * .3)),
        ),
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Color(this.widget.color1),
              Color(this.widget.color2),
            ],
            begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 1.00),
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(this.widget.sliderHeight * paddingFactor,
            2, this.widget.sliderHeight * paddingFactor, 2),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '${this.widget.min}',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: this.widget.sliderHeight * .3,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: this.widget.sliderHeight * .1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: SliderTheme(
                  data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
                    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.5),
                    trackHeight: 4.0,
                    thumbShape: CustomSliderThumbCircle(
                      thumbRadius: this.widget.sliderHeight * .4,
                      darkColor: this.widget.color1,
                      min: this.widget.min,
                      max: this.widget.max,
                    ),
                    overlayColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
                  ),
                  child: Slider(
                      value: currentValue,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          currentValue = value;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: this.widget.sliderHeight * .1,
            ),
            Text(
              '${this.widget.max}',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: this.widget.sliderHeight * .3,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: I'm printing it to the console within this widget. It's at the bottom in the onPressed parameter:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Mood', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'WorkSans')),
        backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF4F1BB),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          //Mood title
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('How are you feeling?',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[800],
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontFamily: 'WorkSans'))),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          //Mood slider
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child:moodSlider),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          //Sleep title
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('How long did you sleep?',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[800],
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontFamily: 'WorkSans'))),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          //Sleep slider
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: //SliderWidget(
                  //     sliderHeight: 48,
                  //     min: 0,
                  //     max: 12,
                  //     color1: 0xFF766E87,
                  //     color2: 0xFF766E87)
                  sleepSlider),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          //Save button
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Save'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                color: PrimaryColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  print(moodSlider.number);
                }, //_save(moodValue, sleepValue),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you show where are you printing the value and how are you printing it?

Comment: I added the code I used. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one getter named `number` defined in your code..

```
int get number => currentValue.round();
```

..which is defined in `_SliderWidgetState` class. Not in `SliderWidget` class. These 2 are 2 different classes. So when you write `moodSlider.number`, you are not calling the above getter. Because `moodSlider` is an instance of `SliderWidget` class and the getter is defined in the other class. Instead, by writing `moodSlider.number`, what you are doing is - you are accessing the member variable `number` of the `SliderWidget` class..

```
class SliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double sliderHeight;
  final int min;
  final int max;
  final fullWidth;
  final int color1;
  final int color2;
  final int number;         //<-- this one here

  SliderWidget(
      {this.sliderHeight,
      this.max,
      this.min,
      this.fullWidth = false,
      this.color1,
      this.color2,
      this.number});

  @override
  _SliderWidgetState createState() => _SliderWidgetState();
}
```

..and this member variable `number` is never assigned a value. That is why it always prints `null`.

*Edit:*

For this to work, we can add an `onChanged` callback to the `SliderWidget`, just like the `Slider` widget has. We can make this callback to accept a `int` value parameter, so we can round it from inside `_SliderWidgetState` and pass to the callback. I made a demo on dartpad. You can see it here - https://dartpad.dev/dc8fd327ff5b94edff6c6f6fe3fea17c

Comment: Oh that makes total sense. Thank you, but do you know how to fix it? I tried calling the original getter to make a getter and setter in the SliderWidget class, but it won't allow it. It says, "Instance member 'currentValue' can't be accessed using static access."

Comment: @StephinaPascho I have edited the answer to include how we can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

As @JigarPatel said, you're calling not calling `getter` of your `State` class but you are calling it from the `SliderWidget` class whose number value is `null`

You can try updating the `SliderWidget` to a `Stateless Widget` See example below:

```
class SliderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double sliderHeight;
  final int min;
  final int max;
  final fullWidth;
  final int color1;
  final int color2;
  final double currentValue;
  final ValueChanged<double> onChanged; 
  
  SliderWidget(
      {this.sliderHeight,
      this.max,
      this.min,
      this.fullWidth = false,
      this.color1,
      this.color2,
      this.currentValue, this.onChanged});

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double paddingFactor = .2;

    if ( fullWidth) paddingFactor = .3;

    return Container(
      width:  fullWidth
          ? double.infinity
          : ( sliderHeight) * 5.5,
      height: ( sliderHeight),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(( sliderHeight * .3)),
        ),
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Color( color1),
              Color( color2),
            ],
            begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 1.00),
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB( sliderHeight * paddingFactor,
            2,  sliderHeight * paddingFactor, 2),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$min',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize:  sliderHeight * .3,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width:  sliderHeight * .1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: SliderTheme(
                  data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
                    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.5),
                    trackHeight: 4.0,
                    thumbShape: CustomSliderThumbCircle(
                      thumbRadius:  sliderHeight * .4,
                      darkColor:  color1,
                      min:  min,
                      max:  max,
                    ),
                    overlayColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
                  ),
                  child: Slider(
                      value: currentValue,
                      onChanged: onChanged),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width:  sliderHeight * .1,
            ),
            Text(
              '$max',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize:  sliderHeight * .3,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In `onChanged` callback you will get the value of the slider.